# What's the difference between semi-supervised VAEs and conditional VAEs?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, comparison, variational-autoencoder

Can someone explain the difference? I'm assuming the difference is just that the neural nets representing the encoder and decoder are trained in a semi-supervised manner in semi-supervised VAE, which in conditional the approximation to the posterior and the posterior's distributions are conditioned on some labels? So, I'm guessing that semi-supervised VAE affects the loss evaluation, whereas, in conditional VAEs, the inference network is conditioned on another label as well?